# Sonarqube + Jmeter error in jtl file

Tags: jmeter, sonarqube

i install Sonarqube with Jmeter Plugin. I have my simple test in Jmeter with:

```
Threads group
   Http Sampler
       Assertion Results
```

and i save the result in local, with jtl extension.

Now i have configure Local jtl file in jmeter plugin for sonar, for my project.

But now if i try to test my project i have this error:

```
ERROR - Cannot analyse project 'My project'
es.excentia.jmeter.report.server.testresults.JtlReaderException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '1' (code 49) in prolog; expected '<'
```

Comment: Hi, Were you able to publish your PERF Jmeter results in Sonar? What version of SonarQube you are using? Im now getting the jtl file in XML format as per Dmitri's answer and the error message is gone but still NOT SonarQube 5.1 is not able to publish the data using JMeter widget in a project's dashboard in Sonar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that sonarqube expects JMeter result file to be in XML format and by [default it is CSV](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html).

Results file output format is controllable via `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` property, supported values are `xml` and `csv`, default is csv.

Depending on how you launch your JMeter test the property can be set in different ways:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   ```
2. Look for this property in *jmeter.properties* file, uncomment and change its value to xml
3. If you run JMeter in [command-line mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) the property can be passed via -J argument as

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan.jmx -l /path/to/results/file/jtl
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on JMeter's property types and ways of overriding.